# Python twitter based Sentimental analysis

Tags: python, twitter, sentiment-analysis

this is an error I got that in twitter based sentiment data analysis
in main

> tweets = api.Get_tweets(query = 'Dengue', count = 200) AttributeError:
>   'TwitterClient' object has no attribute 'Get_tweets' >>>

```
def get_tweets(self, query, count = 10):
            tweets = []
    try:



        fetched_tweets = self.api.search(q = query, count = count)


        for tweet in fetched_tweets:
                            parsed_tweet = {}


            parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text

            parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.text)


            if tweet.retweet_count > 0:

                if parsed_tweet not in tweets:
                    tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
            else:
                tweets.append(parsed_tweet)


        return tweets

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:

        print("Error : " + str(e))

def main():

api = TwitterClient()

tweets = api.get_tweets(query = 'Dengue', count = 200)
```

Comment: between the query you are sending `Dengue` is my username o-0 :D

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the indentation you're using, it seems that `get_tweets` isn't a member of `TwitterClient`.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

class TwitterClient:
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    def get_tweets(self, query, count = 10):
        tweets = []
        try:
            fetched_tweets = self.api.search(q = query, count = count)

            for tweet in fetched_tweets:
                parsed_tweet = {}
                parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text
                parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.text)

                if tweet.retweet_count > 0:
                    if parsed_tweet not in tweets:
                        tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
                else:
                    tweets.append(parsed_tweet)

            return tweets

        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print("Error : " + str(e))

def main():
    client = TwitterClient()
    tweets = client.get_tweets(query = 'Dengue', count = 200)

main()
```

This code ensures that `get_tweets` is a member of `TwitterClient`. Also, noticed that I renamed `api` in `main()` to `client`, which might be less confusing, considering the convention of using `self.api`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\gra.py", line 54, in <module>
    class TwitterClient:
  File "C:\Python27\gra.py", line 55, in TwitterClient
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
NameError: name 'auth' is not defined
>>>

Comment: I updated the code to include the Tweepy OAuthHandler. You'll need to include your Twitter api keys.

Comment: I already included sir kindly give some source so that i send the code to u